# circular logic: saying addition in commutative because it is commutative

Tags: logic

We know $ (\mathbb{C}, +, \cdot) $ is a field because all of the field axioms apply here, with one of them being commutativity.

I wanted to prove something and I wrote that addition in $ \mathbb{C} $ is commutative because $ \mathbb{C} $ is a field. Would that be considered circular logic?

After all, I'm saying:

addition in $ \mathbb{C} $ is commutative $ \Rightarrow $ addition in $ \mathbb{C} $ is commutative

Comment: When $\mathbb{C}$ and its operations are defined, all the field properties are obviously proved. We don't just assume them, they are true. But I believe you were just solving an exercise in which you are allowed to use these properties.

Comment: @AdamRubinson but it's not that addition in $ \mathbb{C} $ is commutative because $ \mathbb{C} $ is a field, we consider $ \mathbb{C} $ a field beacuse addition in it is commutative

Comment: @AdamRubinson Please write $\mathbb{C}$, not $C$.

Comment: In the question, when you say, "We know $ (\mathbb{C}, +, \cdot) $ is a field because all of the field axioms apply here". Can you say precisely what you mean by $ (\mathbb{C}, +, \cdot) $?

Comment: I have found that \Bbb C and \mathbb C both give $\mathbb C$ in LaTex.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a circular argument; that perception arises from the logical form of a definition type employed in mathematics.

Basically, we actually say

$x\,is\, Y\leftrightarrow c_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge c_{n}$

The left-hand side is the *concept* formally defined (*definiendum*) to be applied to some object $x$. The right-hand side comprises the formal constituents of the left-hand side (*definiens*) for $x$ to be satisfied.

So, from left to right, we begin with a concept attributed to an object, then show some $c_{k}$ holds; if we can't, then the attribution on the left-hand side is false.

**Addendum**

For those interested in conceptual issues concerning mathematical concepts, their definitions and roles in proofs, I'd recommend the marvelous book by Imre Lakatos, *[Proofs and Refutations: The Logic of Mathematical Discovery](https://archive.org/details/proofsrefutation0000laka/page/n1/mode/1up)*.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is circular logic. A better argument is as follows:

---

The complex numbers $\mathbb C$ are defined as the set of all objects of the form $a\hat +\mathrm ib$, where $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $\mathrm i$ is the imaginary unit. *(I have used the symbol $\hat +$ because we cannot immediately assume complex addition has the same properties as real addition $+$.)*  Given two complex numbers $a\hat +\mathrm ib$ and $x\hat +\mathrm i y$ where $(a,b)~,~(c,d)\in\mathbb R^2$, we define complex addition as
$$(a\hat +\mathrm ib)\hat +(c\hat +\mathrm id)=(a+c)\hat +\mathrm i(c+d)$$

*Lemma:* Addition in $\mathbb C$ is commutative if addition in $\mathbb R$ is commutative.

*Proof:* This is immediate, i.e
$$(c\hat +\mathrm id)\hat +(a\hat +\mathrm ib)=(c+a)\hat +\mathrm i(d+c) \\ =(a+c)\hat +\mathrm i(c+d) \\ =(a\hat +\mathrm ib)\hat +(c\hat +\mathrm id)$$

If we accept as an **axiom** that addition $+$ in $\mathbb R$ is commutative, then we have shown that addition in $\mathbb C$, as defined above, is commutative, and, having essentially identical properties to addition in $\mathbb R$, can be reasonably denoted with the same symbol.

Comment: This is true assuming the addition in $\mathbb{R}$ is commutative, which might lead someone else to asking the same question about $\mathbb{R}$. In order to prove this we have to go back to the definition of $\mathbb{Q}$, then to $\mathbb{Z}$, then to $\mathbb{N}$. All of them can be proved formally using the definitions. But of course we usually work with all these numbers long before we formally define them, so for a long period of our life we just accept their field properties as facts.

Comment: @Mark Of course, but usually in the context of an introductory complex analysis course (as I believe to be the context of this question from the asker) such proofs are way outside of the scope of the course.